# Layout orientation changes without activity interaction

Tags: android, layout, orientation

Since working with Android I'm curious about how I can let Android do everything in respect to orientation change (layout vs. layout-land).

Currently I have to feed the correct number of db columns and views to the cursor adapter. Is this the correct way or do I miss something? How do you guys do that?

Please have a look at the two SimpleCursorAdapter where I feed the same layout name of  both existing layouts (there's on in layout and one in layout-land). The only difference is the additional db column "type" and the additional view "R.id.activities_row_text3".

Is this the correct way?

```
Cursor cursor;
SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter = null;
if ((cursor = db.fetchActivities(connection)) != null) {
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation; 
    if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                                      this,
                                      R.layout.activities_row,
                                      cursor,
                                      new String[] {
                                          "name",
                                          "time" },
                                      new int[] {
                                          R.id.activities_row_text1,
                                          R.id.activities_row_text2 });
    } else if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                                      this,
                                      R.layout.activities_row,
                                      cursor,
                                      new String[] {
                                          "name",
                                          "time",
                                          "type" },
                                      new int[] {
                                          R.id.activities_row_text1,
                                          R.id.activities_row_text2,
                                          R.id.activities_row_text3 });
    }
    if (simpleCursorAdapter != null) {
        setListAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to create `simpleCursorAdapter` only once, while starting Activity. Then you can use method `SimpleCursorAdapter.changeCursorAndColumns()` (or `bindView()`) when change orientation occurs. You may need to invalidate list to see changes (`notifyDataSetInvalidated()`).

To avoid restarting activity when orientation change occurs, see [Handling orientation changes yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967903/handling-orientation-changes-yourself)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The code shown above is part of every activities onCreate because my apps usually support different layouts. I came to the conclusion that I must be doing something terribly wrong. With different screen sizes and orientations the list of different cursor/adapter/view combinations did increase and I thought "ask the pros". Consider as shown two layouts: One with 2 columns and one with three columns (just a test - it's usually more complicated). Do you use two different cursor or one cursor fetching all? How/where do you decide what columns/views to use? Thanks hjw

Comment: Use one cursor for one kind of query (wrap Cursor in own class and provide convenient constructors). Write own adapter class instead of using SimpleAdapters - looks compilcated at the beginning, but it becomes easy quickly. Reuse those classes in multiple activities. You can pre-define layouts or change layout properies (like column number) in the runtime, both solutions have pros and cons. Don't mix UI with data structures - you will be able to improve code later, after learning new techniques.